# What happens when an entry in an array of fixed entry size is smaller than the fixed entry size?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, go-ethereum

Let’s say you have an array with a fixed size for each entry (ex: a string or some bytes).  What happens if you store a smaller entry? Does the entry get padded with some empty value (zeroes) or does it simply get stored?

Edit:

Sorry for the error, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: But `string` and `bytes` are _not_ fixed sizes.

Comment: The question is not very clear. Are you talking about fixed size of array or the fixed size of dataType stored in array?